# JSON parser tip in C

Tags: c, json, api

first of all i know there are lots of lists out there and over the last 3 days i probably checked out 10+ free json-parsers. The reason I am still looking is probably because I didn't find working examples / infos / whatnot to get what i want working quite simply. I'm quite sure that this will end up being reported as reask but nevertheless i beg for someone with JSON in C expierence to give me a quick tip since this would probably safe me hours of googling and looking into an API where i need about 10 lines of code or something.

The data is passed as a string delimered with a ','

```
JSON Data (Array)
string, string, int (Array)
```

`Username,Password,2.4.0`

Basically all i need is an api which offers something similar as

[SWF] JSON->Stringify();

`["Username","Password","2.4.0"]`

Sorry if you consider that an annoying repost but thanks for reading anyway.

[image: What I want to do in C]

[image]

Comment: how is that json? that is a comma delimited string. You want the comma string turned into JSON?

Comment: json has to have `{` `}`

Comment: @true - Untrue!!  Both you and the OP should go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax -- it only takes 5-10 minutes to learn.  In JSON `[]` brackets an "array", and a "legal" JSON payload can have either an "array" or an "object" as it's outermost structure.

Comment: @Hot Licks oh yeah you are right. I forgot

Comment: json.org lists 17 JSON toolkits for C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up with something like this. Just posting in case someone comes across something similar. Anyway I ended up using [frozen](https://github.com/cesanta/frozen) JSON parser for parsing and [json-parser](https://github.com/udp/json-parser) for validating.

```
BOOL IsNumber(const char *string)
{
    char *pch;
    pch = string;
    while (*pch != '\0')
    {
        if (!isdigit(*pch)) return FALSE;
        pch++;
    }
    return TRUE;
}

char* test(const char *Data)
{
    char *retVal = NULL;
    char *buffer;
    char *ptr;
    int len;

    buffer = (char*)malloc(strlen(Data) + 1);
    strcpy(buffer, Data);
    ptr = strtok(buffer, ",");
    if (ptr)
    {
        len = 2;
        retVal = (char*)malloc(2);
        strcpy(retVal, "[");
        do
        {
            len += strlen(ptr) + 1;
            if (IsNumber(ptr))
            {
                retVal = (char*)realloc(retVal, len);
                sprintf(retVal, "%s%s,", retVal, ptr);
            }
            else
            {
                len += 2;
                retVal = (char*)realloc(retVal, len);
                sprintf(retVal, "%s\"%s\",", retVal, ptr);
            }
            ptr = strtok(NULL, ",");
        }
        while (ptr != NULL);
        retVal[len - 2] = ']';
    }
    free(buffer);
    return retVal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not have any "JSON in C" experience, but I found this question interesting and googled for some C JASON parsers. I came across http://zserge.bitbucket.org/jsmn.html

Well, here is some working Code that does some very basic and NON GENERIC stringify-thing for your input. Maybe that helps :)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "jsmn.h"

#define TOKEN_PRINT(t) \
    printf("start: %d, end: %d, type: %d, size: %d\n", \
            (t).start, (t).end, (t).type, (t).size)

#define IN_POS_LEN(in, t) \
    (in) + (t).start, (t).end - (t).start

int main()
{
    static const char input[] = "['Mark','Secret','2.4.0']";

    /* declare and init jsmn parser as per documentation
    (or as per jsmn_test.c if documentation was not working) */
    jsmn_parser parser;
    jsmntok_t tok[256];
    int r;
    jsmn_init(&parser);

    /* parse input and check for success and expected format */
    r = jsmn_parse(&parser, input, strlen(input), tok, 256);
    if(r >= 0
        && tok[0].type == JSMN_ARRAY)
    {
        /* now, 'stringify' an array of strings */
        int stringNum;
        for(stringNum = 1; stringNum <= tok[0].size; ++stringNum)
        {
            char tmp[128] = {0};
            memcpy(tmp, IN_POS_LEN(input, tok[stringNum]));
            printf("%s%s", tmp, stringNum == tok[0].size ? "\n" : ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

The jsmn library had to be built as per documentation (worked out of the box). Compiling, Linking and Running gives:

```
➜  jsmn  gcc mytest.c -L . -ljsmn; ./a.out
'Mark', 'Secret', '2.4.0'
```

EDIT:
Ok, if i understand you correctly, you just want to generate those login string format from some variables you have in C? Then I think I would not even use any API as it is quite easy with C: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90a14edbe59db74a

Comment: I'm gonna check it tomorrow in more detail I just ran the code and briefly checked what's happening basically you're doing it in the wrong direction not sure how much effort to change that will definitely gonna try as soon as I get up. Added some screens to clearify what I want to do ;)

Comment: Thought about that but I wanted to stick to the code as much as possible since if the software is completed later I probably do not have the time to fix it and stop it for hours.